# How to properly use cin.clear an cin.ignore

Tags: c++, error-handling

```
    int main()
{
    int oddeven = 1;
    int modulotwo;
    // Simple loop since no reason to check 0
    while(oddeven != 0){
        //user input
        cout << "\n\nIn while loop\n";
        cout << "Input number to determine if it is odd or even.\n";
        cin >> oddeven;
        //check to see if input succesful
        if(!(cin.fail())) {
            cout << "In if loop\n";
            cout << "Divide by two and put in modulotwo.\n";
            //check to see if odd or even by dividing by 2
            modulotwo = oddeven % 2;
            cout << "Output modulotwo: ";
            //visual confirmation of remainder
            cout << modulotwo << "\n";
            if (modulotwo == 0) {
                cout << "Check modulotwo against 0\n";
                cout << "The number " << oddeven << " is even.\n";

            }
            else {
                cout << "The number " << oddeven << " is odd.\n";

            }
        }
        //If input not succesful
        else {
            cout << "In else statement. Set oddeven to 1\n";
            //set oddeven to 1 to stop exit
            oddeven = 1;
            cout << "Not a usable number, please input integer number." << endl;
            cout << "Run cin.clear\n";
            cin.clear();
            cout << "Run cin.ignore\n";
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());

        }
    }

}
```

I have above, a "simple" code to check whether a number was odd or even. I am attempting to add error correction to it to make sure the input is correct type. I was pointed to cin.clear an cin.ignore.
My issue is, if I cause an error it correctly drops into the else statement, but that is it. It will no longer run the rest. I am assuming it from the cin.ignore. 
How do I get it to properly clear the error and return to the input loop?
If I remove the cin.ignore, I get a continuous loop telling me that 1 is odd without waiting for any input.

The extra output text was my way of trying to track where the code was and what it was doing.

Edit. I had actually had the cin.ignore commented out before posting here. I was trying to research the problem myself and had come across a comment about it looking for a newline character, but as you all have found out also, it doesn't work. The problem shows up when entering a letter rather than any number, too larger or otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My issue is, if I cause an error it correctly drops into the else statement, but that is it. It will no longer run the rest.

The problem is in the line

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), "\n");
```

The second argument needs to be a character, not a string.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Increase the warning level of your compiler to detect such errors.

By using `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall`, I get the following warning/error message.

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:43:70: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::int_type {aka int}’ [-fpermissive]
          cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), "\n");
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from socc.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:657:5: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::ignore(std::streamsize, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::int_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::streamsize = long int; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::int_type = int]’
     basic_istream<char>::
```

Comment: I edited the original post. The "\n" was just me trying something I had read, about the ignore looking for a new-line character.

Comment: @ButchCrockett, yes, it does look for the newline character.  That's why you need to use `'\n'`, the newline character, not `"\n"`, which is a string.

Comment: @ButchCrockett, a general suggestion. Please don't edit your posted code in ways that makes any posted answers out of sync with the new code.

Comment: I thank you very much. I can't tell you just how frustrating it was reading your comment and not realized the different ( the single quote instead of double). Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @ButchCrockett, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code myself and immediately my compiler gave me an error message pointing to  this line:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), "\n");
```

Your second argument in the cin.ignore function should be a character, not a string. Simply change your quotation marks and edit the line to show

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

It should work just how you want after that :). I would consider updating your IDE or compiler to show better error messages/ call stacks.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't connecting the dots, or rather the single v double quotes. I did get the same error, I just wasn't correctly understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

cin.clear(1000, '\n');

1000 being the number of characters to ignore, change it to whatever you want